# How to manipulate data in jQuery for list data coming from Hibernate

Tags: jquery

Code in js page as below

```
$('#showAll').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url  :  rootURL,
    dataType : 'json',
 contentType : 'application/json',
     success : function(data){              
                    $('#empList tbody').remove();
                    var employee =data.employee;
                    alert(employee.ID+"---"+employee.name);
                    $(employee).each(function(){
                        $('#empList').append('<tbody><tr><td><a  href="#" id="' + $(this).ID + '">' +
                        $(this).find('ID').text()+'</a></td><td> ' + $(this).find('name').text()+ '</td><td> ' +
                        $(this).find('sal').text()+'</td></tr></tbody>');
                    });
                }
    });
});
```

Response is coming as below. how can i manipulate in jQuery

```
{"employee":[{"ID":"1","name":"vcv","sal":"4545"},{"ID":"2","name":"dfdf","sal":"dfdf"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this inside `success` method:

```
var employee = data.employee;
$.each(employee, function (index, value) {
    $('#empList').append(value.ID + ' ' + value.name + ' ' + value.sal);
});
```